issue in PostgrelSQL 15.3 with partition pruning
I have two tables partitioned by range on column day,(this is an oversimplification for a more complex design), tables appear similar but day field refers to completly different concept than day in second table. Table events has about 100,000 records, table weather about 2 billion
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events
(
   id  bigint NOT NULL,
   day date NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (day, id)
       USING INDEX TABLESPACE tabpart,
) PARTITION BY RANGE (day)

TABLESPACE tabpart;

CREATE TABLE events_2024 PARTITION OF events    FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-01-01') TO ('2025-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather
(
   id  bigint NOT NULL,
   day date NOT NULL,
   tmax numeric(3,1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT weather_pkey PRIMARY KEY (day, id)
       USING INDEX TABLESPACE tabpart,
) PARTITION BY RANGE (day)

TABLESPACE tabpart;

CREATE TABLE weather_1991 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1991-01-01') TO ('1992-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1992 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1992-01-01') TO ('1993-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1993 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1993-01-01') TO ('1994-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1994 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1994-01-01') TO ('1995-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1995 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1995-01-01') TO ('1996-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1996 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1996-01-01') TO ('1997-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1997 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1997-01-01') TO ('1998-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1998 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1998-01-01') TO ('1999-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_1999 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('1999-01-01') TO ('2000-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2000 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2000-01-01') TO ('2001-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2001 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2001-01-01') TO ('2002-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2002 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2002-01-01') TO ('2003-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2003 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2003-01-01') TO ('2004-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2004 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2004-01-01') TO ('2005-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2005 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2005-01-01') TO ('2006-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2006 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-01-01') TO ('2007-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2007 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2007-01-01') TO ('2008-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2008 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2008-01-01') TO ('2009-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2009 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2009-01-01') TO ('2010-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2010 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2010-01-01') TO ('2011-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2011 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2011-01-01') TO ('2012-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2012 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2012-01-01') TO ('2013-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2013 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2013-01-01') TO ('2014-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2014 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-01-01') TO ('2015-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2015 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2015-01-01') TO ('2016-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2016 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2016-01-01') TO ('2017-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2017 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2017-01-01') TO ('2018-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2018 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2018-01-01') TO ('2019-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2019 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-01-01') TO ('2020-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2020 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01') TO ('2021-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2021 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-01-01') TO ('2022-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2022 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01') TO ('2023-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2023 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01') TO ('2024-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;
CREATE TABLE weather_2024 PARTITION OF weather    FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-01-01') TO ('2025-01-01') TABLESPACE tabpart;

Now if I execute this query:
select avg(value) 
from   events  e
join   weather w on (e.id = w.id)
where  w.day between e.day - 10 and e.day + 21;  

The query planner doesn't trigger partition pruning limiting seq scan to 2024 partition instead goes in full seq scan for all partitions, instead I do the same in Oracle 19c and partition pruning works fine, of course all related parameters for partition pruning are on.
Here is the execution plan:
HashAggregate  (cost=90136968.42..90138196.60 rows=98254 width=40) (actual time=482709.895..482747.827 rows=66552 loops=1)
   Output: w.idgrid, avg(w.temperature_max)
   Group Key: w.idgrid
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 31761kB
   Buffers: shared hit=35478237
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=2190.20..89507469.47 rows=125899790 width=14) (actual time=474894.521..482209.735 rows=1833282 loops=1)
         Output: w.idgrid, w.temperature_max
         Hash Cond: (w.idgrid = c.idgrid)
         Join Filter: ((w.day >= (c.day - 10)) AND (w.day <= (c.day + 21)))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 811759233
         Buffers: shared hit=35478237
               Buffers: shared hit=35477877
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1979 w_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_1.idgrid, w_1.temperature_max, w_1.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1980 w_2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_2.idgrid, w_2.temperature_max, w_2.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1981 w_3  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_3.idgrid, w_3.temperature_max, w_3.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1982 w_4  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_4.idgrid, w_4.temperature_max, w_4.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1983 w_5  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_5.idgrid, w_5.temperature_max, w_5.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1984 w_6  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_6.idgrid, w_6.temperature_max, w_6.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1985 w_7  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_7.idgrid, w_7.temperature_max, w_7.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1986 w_8  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_8.idgrid, w_8.temperature_max, w_8.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1987 w_9  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_9.idgrid, w_9.temperature_max, w_9.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1988 w_10  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_10.idgrid, w_10.temperature_max, w_10.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1989 w_11  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_11.idgrid, w_11.temperature_max, w_11.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1990 w_12  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_12.idgrid, w_12.temperature_max, w_12.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1991 w_13  (cost=0.00..1503878.44 rows=49967444 width=18) (actual time=342.840..5913.373 rows=49964796 loops=1)
                     Output: w_13.idgrid, w_13.temperature_max, w_13.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1004204
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1992 w_14  (cost=0.00..1512690.08 rows=50107008 width=18) (actual time=0.042..6048.441 rows=50101828 loops=1)
                     Output: w_14.idgrid, w_14.temperature_max, w_14.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1011620
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1993 w_15  (cost=0.00..1508081.68 rows=49957568 width=18) (actual time=0.080..6688.314 rows=49964184 loops=1)
                     Output: w_15.idgrid, w_15.temperature_max, w_15.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1008506
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1994 w_16  (cost=0.00..1508701.48 rows=49962048 width=18) (actual time=0.057..8371.578 rows=49959860 loops=1)
                     Output: w_16.idgrid, w_16.temperature_max, w_16.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1009081
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1995 w_17  (cost=0.00..1560116.28 rows=49928628 width=18) (actual time=0.092..7439.766 rows=49925217 loops=1)
                     Output: w_17.idgrid, w_17.temperature_max, w_17.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1060830
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1996 w_18  (cost=0.00..1562675.80 rows=50053880 width=18) (actual time=0.103..8949.875 rows=50061840 loops=1)
                     Output: w_18.idgrid, w_18.temperature_max, w_18.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1062137
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1997 w_19  (cost=0.00..1560511.28 rows=49946528 width=18) (actual time=0.096..8253.548 rows=49925474 loops=1)
                     Output: w_19.idgrid, w_19.temperature_max, w_19.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1061046
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1998 w_20  (cost=0.00..1558069.28 rows=49955328 width=18) (actual time=0.096..7342.791 rows=49961472 loops=1)
                     Output: w_20.idgrid, w_20.temperature_max, w_20.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1058516
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_1999 w_21  (cost=0.00..1557345.24 rows=49958124 width=18) (actual time=0.049..7186.280 rows=49960911 loops=1)
                     Output: w_21.idgrid, w_21.temperature_max, w_21.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1057764
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2000 w_22  (cost=0.00..1562944.16 rows=50095116 width=18) (actual time=0.048..8849.576 rows=50098278 loops=1)
                     Output: w_22.idgrid, w_22.temperature_max, w_22.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1061993
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2001 w_23  (cost=0.00..1557918.96 rows=49969696 width=18) (actual time=0.098..7440.664 rows=49961045 loops=1)
                     Output: w_23.idgrid, w_23.temperature_max, w_23.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1058222
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2002 w_24  (cost=0.00..1557220.80 rows=49958280 width=18) (actual time=0.055..6823.835 rows=49961485 loops=1)
                     Output: w_24.idgrid, w_24.temperature_max, w_24.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1057638
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2003 w_25  (cost=0.00..1555614.04 rows=49965804 width=18) (actual time=0.089..6509.970 rows=49961214 loops=1)
                     Output: w_25.idgrid, w_25.temperature_max, w_25.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1055956
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2004 w_26  (cost=0.00..1571204.76 rows=50084576 width=18) (actual time=0.059..8899.957 rows=50081989 loops=1)
                     Output: w_26.idgrid, w_26.temperature_max, w_26.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1070359
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2005 w_27  (cost=0.00..1568760.52 rows=49951252 width=18) (actual time=0.095..7481.493 rows=49949063 loops=1)
                     Output: w_27.idgrid, w_27.temperature_max, w_27.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1069248
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2006 w_28  (cost=0.00..1569330.48 rows=49949748 width=18) (actual time=0.047..8443.618 rows=49949126 loops=1)
                     Output: w_28.idgrid, w_28.temperature_max, w_28.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1069833
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2007 w_29  (cost=0.00..1570369.96 rows=49953296 width=18) (actual time=0.096..6984.137 rows=49952444 loops=1)
                     Output: w_29.idgrid, w_29.temperature_max, w_29.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1070837
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2008 w_30  (cost=0.00..1576169.00 rows=50088000 width=18) (actual time=0.049..7615.967 rows=50089242 loops=1)
                     Output: w_30.idgrid, w_30.temperature_max, w_30.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1075289
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2009 w_31  (cost=0.00..1570969.64 rows=49958964 width=18) (actual time=0.095..6585.050 rows=49952470 loops=1)
                     Output: w_31.idgrid, w_31.temperature_max, w_31.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1071380
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2010 w_32  (cost=0.00..1570515.80 rows=49952780 width=18) (actual time=0.050..8933.361 rows=49952167 loops=1)
                     Output: w_32.idgrid, w_32.temperature_max, w_32.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1070988
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2011 w_33  (cost=0.00..1567517.48 rows=49934548 width=18) (actual time=0.094..7269.601 rows=49937858 loops=1)
                     Output: w_33.idgrid, w_33.temperature_max, w_33.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1068172
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2012 w_34  (cost=0.00..1573373.52 rows=50075152 width=18) (actual time=0.050..8898.780 rows=50073637 loops=1)
                     Output: w_34.idgrid, w_34.temperature_max, w_34.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1072622
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2013 w_35  (cost=0.00..1570286.44 rows=49940344 width=18) (actual time=0.097..7843.212 rows=49936131 loops=1)
                     Output: w_35.idgrid, w_35.temperature_max, w_35.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1070883
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2014 w_36  (cost=0.00..1570874.32 rows=49935432 width=18) (actual time=0.046..7362.644 rows=49934110 loops=1)
                     Output: w_36.idgrid, w_36.temperature_max, w_36.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1071520
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2015 w_37  (cost=0.00..1567038.16 rows=49931416 width=18) (actual time=0.111..6368.080 rows=49934020 loops=1)
                     Output: w_37.idgrid, w_37.temperature_max, w_37.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1067724
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2016 w_38  (cost=0.00..1566878.64 rows=50069664 width=18) (actual time=0.048..8981.667 rows=50071237 loops=1)
                     Output: w_38.idgrid, w_38.temperature_max, w_38.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1066182
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2017 w_39  (cost=0.00..1562364.08 rows=49937808 width=18) (actual time=0.092..7598.168 rows=49935350 loops=1)
                     Output: w_39.idgrid, w_39.temperature_max, w_39.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1062986
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2018 w_40  (cost=0.00..1562093.72 rows=49940472 width=18) (actual time=0.094..9128.367 rows=49935888 loops=1)
                     Output: w_40.idgrid, w_40.temperature_max, w_40.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1062689
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2019 w_41  (cost=0.00..1563649.04 rows=49937904 width=18) (actual time=0.092..6858.006 rows=49937367 loops=1)
                     Output: w_41.idgrid, w_41.temperature_max, w_41.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1064270
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2020 w_42  (cost=0.00..1566165.08 rows=50062908 width=18) (actual time=0.095..9200.812 rows=50067701 loops=1)
                     Output: w_42.idgrid, w_42.temperature_max, w_42.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1065536
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2021 w_43  (cost=0.00..1561963.52 rows=49929852 width=18) (actual time=0.105..7038.267 rows=49931540 loops=1)
                     Output: w_43.idgrid, w_43.temperature_max, w_43.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1062665
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2022 w_44  (cost=0.00..1563302.24 rows=49946524 width=18) (actual time=0.052..8547.824 rows=49948885 loops=1)
                     Output: w_44.idgrid, w_44.temperature_max, w_44.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1063837
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2023 w_45  (cost=0.00..1564803.44 rows=49937144 width=18) (actual time=0.093..6234.920 rows=49937469 loops=1)
                     Output: w_45.idgrid, w_45.temperature_max, w_45.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=1065432
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2024 w_46  (cost=0.00..782714.32 rows=23480232 width=18) (actual time=0.096..3757.702 rows=23529617 loops=1)
                     Output: w_46.idgrid, w_46.temperature_max, w_46.day
                     Buffers: shared hit=547912
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2025 w_47  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_47.idgrid, w_47.temperature_max, w_47.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2026 w_48  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_48.idgrid, w_48.temperature_max, w_48.day
               ->  Seq Scan on weather_2027 w_49  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: w_49.idgrid, w_49.temperature_max, w_49.day
         ->  Hash  (cost=1358.28..1358.28 rows=66553 width=12) (actual time=19.735..19.738 rows=66552 loops=1)
               Output: c.day, c.idgrid
               Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4144kB
               Buffers: shared hit=360
               ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1358.28 rows=66553 width=12) (actual time=0.033..10.108 rows=66552 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=360
                     ->  Seq Scan on events_2023 c_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Output: c_1.day, c_1.idgrid
                     ->  Seq Scan on events_2024 c_2  (cost=0.00..1025.52 rows=66552 width=12) (actual time=0.018..5.889 rows=66552 loops=1)
                           Output: c_2.day, c_2.idgrid
                           Buffers: shared hit=360
 Query Identifier: 8183848394416207525
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=451 read=36
   I/O Timings: shared/local read=11.284
 Planning Time: 21.057 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 114
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 11.569 ms, Inlining 10.237 ms, Optimization 204.663 ms, Emission 129.446 ms, Total 355.914 ms
 Execution Time: 482763.833 ms

Have you some suggestion to understand why partition pruning has not been triggered?

Please show the execution plan for the PostgreSQL query.

https://www.pgexplain.dev/plan/3f0ae78d-4e70-41da-8350-f12a3b27d0c9#plan

Sorry, but such a plan does not exist in PostgreSQL. Perhaps the visualizer is mangling your data. Try explain.depesz.com.

https://explain.depesz.com/s/BhEO

Thanks. Did you set enable_partitionwise_join = on?

Yes, of course.

It's easy to understand: no such capability has been added to the query planner. You will have to add WHERE conditions that use constants.

This is sad, unfortunately PostgreSQL behavior seems still behind to Oracle efficiency with partitioning plans and PostgreSQL query planner can easily access to histograms bounds to evaluate the partitioning pruning path...
Anyway I will try with a stored procedure returning dynamic query  and with redundant filter condition where day between min and max event, so to get constant dates.
